# how to find last occurrence of a parent in a given below string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a below pattern string.

```
'GP0|#92ca7467-4c0d-461a-aac4-2bc8fd9ee16a;L0|#092ca7467-4c0d-461a-aac4-2bc8fd9ee16a|Analysts;GTSet|#7fa22453-62b1-4bec-b73d-01ccf115d558;GPP|#fd613617-ba9d-43e5-9990-95f96f94af2a;GPP|#ba395283-6169-4c6d-84d5-1cecb3c2a73b;GP0|#a547b95c-0dfa-4f42-b540-e55872fb2e81;L0|#0a547b95c-0dfa-4f42-b540-e55872fb2e81|Awards;GP0|#c4363ae8-8608-4309-92f0-5079c69b47e4;L0|#0c4363ae8-8608-4309-92f0-5079c69b47e4|Digital Workplace;GP0|#1976b988-a993-4f13-a1e8-d847138eebc6;L0|#01976b988-a993-4f13-a1e8-d847138eebc6|Intranet;GP0|#a68218df-b9e8-4f07-bfff-22cab83bbc0d;L0|#0a68218df-b9e8-4f07-bfff-22cab83bbc0d|Microsoft;GP0|#57737444-1a1b-4c87-a479-1548b58e44e3;L0|#057737444-1a1b-4c87-a479-1548b58e44e3|Research;'
```

I want to get last occurrence of the pattern which starts with GPP and ends with ;

```
expected output: GPP|#ba395283-6169-4c6d-84d5-1cecb3c2a73b;
```

I tried this regex `/GPP\|.+?;/i` but it gives the first occurrence i.e. `GPP|#fd613617-ba9d-43e5-9990-95f96f94af2a;`

Answer (score 1):

As they come after each other, you can match the pattern and assert that there is no following occurrence starting with the same pattern:

As the match ends on a single character, you can match any character except `;` instead using a negated character class.

```
\bGPP\|[^;]+;(?!GPP\|[^;]+;)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZtpbJk/1)